# C# tabcontrol border controls

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to make a tabcontrol border transparent, or to set the color of a tabcontrol?

- Winforms

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone meets the same problem, here's the answer worked for me
[Border TabControl](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/border-tabcontrol-t3243534.html)

As it describes,
Make a NativeTabControl object and Assign the handle of the tabControl of which you want to remove the border. You can use this  NativeTabControl class as an inner class in the form class.
You don't have to change anything inside the inner class. Simply follow the above steps.
All the credits should go to the original designer of the code. I'm just putting it here for anyone who meets the same problem and need a nice and sexy answer!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1
{


public Form1()
{
    // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    this.NativeTabControl1 = new NativeTabControl();
    this.NativeTabControl2 = new NativeTabControl();
    this.NativeTabControl1.AssignHandle(this.TabControl1.Handle);
    this.NativeTabControl2.AssignHandle(this.TabControl2.Handle);
}

private NativeTabControl NativeTabControl1;

private NativeTabControl NativeTabControl2;
private class NativeTabControl : NativeWindow
{

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == TCM_ADJUSTRECT)) {
            RECT rc = (RECT)m.GetLParam(typeof(RECT));
            //Adjust these values to suit, dependant upon Appearance
            rc.Left -= 3;
            rc.Right += 3;
            rc.Top -= 3;
            rc.Bottom += 3;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, true);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private const Int32 TCM_FIRST = 0x1300;
    private const Int32 TCM_ADJUSTRECT = (TCM_FIRST + 40);
    private struct RECT
    {
        public Int32 Left;
        public Int32 Top;
        public Int32 Right;
        public Int32 Bottom;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is a great piece of code, and thanks for spreading it! Just incase anybody doesn't like the fact that there is no top horizontal line separating the Tab buttons from their content down below, simple changing `rc.Top -= 3;` to `rc.Top -= 1;` will put a top horizontal line up there.